# ASP.NET MVC 5 - can the current thread change during single http request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, threadstatic

Sometimes (randomly) I'm faced with my [ThreadStatic] property is null, though it is definitely initialized in the beginning of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes, the thread can change during single http request.

[asp.net mvc3 request thread affinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695542/asp-net-mvc3-request-thread-affinity)

[ThreadStaticAttribute in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791208/threadstaticattribute-in-asp-net)